# How to get ViewModel in Activity in Android SunFlower Project?

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I am studying `MVVM` of Google [Android SunFlower](https://github.com/android/sunflower) project.

For `Fragment`, it gets `viewmodel` like the following

```
private val plantDetailViewModel: PlantDetailViewModel by viewModels {
        InjectorUtils.providePlantDetailViewModelFactory(requireActivity(), args.plantId)
    }
```

I want to try the same method to get `viewmodel` in Activity. but the `requireActivity()`show unresolved reference...

And the `data binding` is not working when I replace it to `this`.

Does it has other pattern can be use for `providePlantDetailViewModelFactory()`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add these to your build.gradle

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
```

**Usage in Activity**

```
val usersViewModel: UsersViewModel by viewModels()
```

**Usage in Fragment**

```
// Get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to this Fragment
val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()

// Get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to its Activity
val viewModel by activityViewModels<MyViewModel>()
```

Comment: Cannot import **activityViewModels**

Answer (score 1):

You need a gradle dependency on `"androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$version"`.

Then you can `import androidx.activity.viewModels` in your Activity.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think so that you can do similar for your `Activity` that's done for `Fragment`.

**Why?**

The delegate function **`viewModels`** is available from **fragment-ktx** library *(Refer [here for reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#extension-functions))* as extension for getting `ViewModel` instance lazily on your value objects using **by** keyword.

And there's no such thing available for *Activities*, for an instance.

So, better is to create your own or find some other way like basic `lazy{}` function from Kotlin standard library and providing logic to it.